# How to select a non-missing value in a group?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, subset

This is a sample data frame:

```
mydata <- data.frame(Id = c(01,01,02,02,02,03,03,04,04,04),
                     Score = c(1,NA,NA,5,78,9,5,NA,3,4),
                     Visit = c(NA, "Yes", "No", NA, NA, "Yes", NA, "Yes", NA, NA))
```

Sample Data:

| ID | Score | Visit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NA |
| 1 | NA | Yes |
| 2 | NA | No |
| 2 | 5 | NA |
| 2 | 78 | NA |
| 3 | 9 | Yes |
| 3 | 5 | NA |
| 4 | NA | Yes |
| 4 | 3 | NA |
| 4 | 4 | NA |

I want to group by Id and select only the non-missing values of the column: Score. But, I would like to retain the information in the Visit column.

Desired Result:

| ID | Score | Visit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Yes |
| 2 | 5 | No |
| 2 | 78 | No |
| 3 | 9 | Yes |
| 3 | 5 | Yes |
| 4 | 3 | Yes |
| 4 | 4 | Yes |

In short, I want to retain the non-Null values in Score and Visit in one row grouped by Id.

Comment: Don't confuse `NULL` with `NA` - they are different in R. I'm a little confused by your operation - in the data you show, `Visit` has exactly 1 non-NA value per ID, and that is what is retained regardless of how many non-NA `Score` rows there are. Is that reliable? Normally I would worry about what happens when there are multiple non-NA values in `Visit`, but perhaps that's not a concern for your data?

Comment: Will a certain `ID` ever have `"Yes"` and `"No"` mixed together under `Visit`?  Or will it be only **(1)** some `"No"`s with possibly some `NA`s; or **(2)** some `"Yes"`s with possibly some `NA`s?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One is to assign the value of the non-NA `Visit` by Id, and then filter the `complete.cases`:

```r
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
  mutate(Visit = max(Visit, na.rm = TRUE), .by = "Id") %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(Score))

#   Id Score Visit
# 1  1     1   Yes
# 2  2     5    No
# 3  2    78    No
# 4  3     9   Yes
# 5  3     5   Yes
# 6  4     3   Yes
# 7  4     4   Yes
```

Another is to use `tidyr::fill`:

```r
mydata %>% 
  tidyr::fill(Visit, .direction = "downup") %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(Score))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `dplyr::reframe()`

```r
mydata <- data.frame(Id = c(01,01,02,02,02,03,03,04,04,04),
                     Score = c(1,NA,NA,5,78,9,5,NA,3,4),
                     Visit = c(NA, "Yes", "No", NA, NA, "Yes", NA, "Yes", NA, NA))

dplyr::reframe(mydata,
        across(c(Score, Visit), \(x) unique(x[!is.na(x)])),
        .by = Id)

#>   Id Score Visit
#> 1  1     1   Yes
#> 2  2     5    No
#> 3  2    78    No
#> 4  3     9   Yes
#> 5  3     5   Yes
#> 6  4     3   Yes
#> 7  4     4   Yes
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This solution finds the unique values of `Score` and `Visit` for each group. It works because the non-missing unique values are the same length in each group across columns. If your data have variable lengths of unique non-missing values across columns, you'll need a more complicated solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using `by`, and `cbind` `complete.cases`, with `unique` Visits `na.omit`ed.

```
by(mydata, mydata$Id, \(x) cbind(x[complete.cases(x[-3]), -3], Visit=unique(na.omit(x$Visit)))) |>
  c(make.row.names=FALSE) |> do.call(what='rbind')
#   Id Score Visit
# 1  1     1   Yes
# 2  2     5    No
# 3  2    78    No
# 4  3     9   Yes
# 5  3     5   Yes
# 6  4     3   Yes
# 7  4     4   Yes
```

If you want to consider @Greg's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76465886/how-do-i-select-a-non-missing-value-in-a-group-in-r#comment134828530_76465886), you could make it more fail-safe by setting non-agreeing Visits to `NA`,

```
by(mydata, mydata$Id, \(x) {
  Visit <- unique(na.omit(x$Visit))
  if (length(Visit) != 1L) {Visit <- NA_character_}
  cbind(x[complete.cases(x[-3]), -3], Visit)
}) |> c(make.row.names=FALSE) |> do.call(what='rbind')
#   Id Score Visit
# 1  1     1   Yes
# 2  2     5    No
# 3  2    78    No
# 4  3     9   Yes
# 5  3     5   Yes
# 6  4     3   Yes
# 7  4     4   Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `na.omit` like below

```
na.omit(
    transform(
        mydata,
        Visit = ave(Visit, Id, FUN = na.omit)
    )
)
```

which gives

```
   Id Score Visit
1   1     1   Yes
4   2     5    No
5   2    78    No
6   3     9   Yes
7   3     5   Yes
9   4     3   Yes
10  4     4   Yes
```